# How to get a list of IP connected in LAN using Air, Flex or Flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex, networking, air, ip

Is it possible using Adobe Air, Flex or Flash to get a list of available IP in a LAN?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ya it is possible using [NetworkInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/NetworkInfo.html#propertySummary) see example [Retrieving a list of network interfaces in Adobe AIR 2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/retrieving_network_interfaces.html)

Hopes that helps